# Unable to open a controller(PHP web page) in 000webhost.com. "error404.000webhost.com/"

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, web-hosting

I have just uploaded all file of my test website to `000webhost.com` domain.
My site is `farazphptest.comxa.com`

I was working on Codeigniter before uploading the site. All of my controllers are working fine on my localhost, but after uploading the site on server when i try to access a controller say `farazphptest.comxa.com/welcome` where "Welcome" is my webpage/controller, it does not work and opens "`error404.000webhost.com/?`" All of my controller including "welcome" are working fine on localhost, but after uploading website on domain only the home page loads perfectly.
This is the 1st time i have put a site on web, do tell me if i am missing out some tricks. I have just simply copied my file on web as stated. Thanks

Here is my .htaccess file used in both for localhost and on server.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /faraztest
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /faraztest/index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is your localhost "windows" and your "webhost" linux.  Windows is not case sensitive, where as linux is.  for windows "Controller" and "controller" are the same, this is not true of linux.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I renamed the controllers folder name. Error still stands.

Comment: This applies to everything including the file names of the controllers, is it "Welcome.php" or "welcome.php".

Comment: yes man! i have tested everything @ArtisiticPhoenix

Comment: this question isnt going that viral, can you help me out for solving this issue? @ArtisiticPhoenix

Comment: id toss these two rules first off "RewriteBase /faraztest"
"RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)", the first one should always end in a slash such as "RewriteBase /" or "RewriteBase /faraztest/"  and this one is as best I can tell backwards "RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)" as indicated by this one "^(.*)$ index.php?$1", I don't know i've never seen that one used anyway in the context of codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following solved my problem

My .htccess file is

```
# index file can be index.php, home.php, default.php etc.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# condition with escaping special chars
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and it worked like charm!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to create sub-domain on `000webhost.com` with project name , and call the project from sub domain url Directly, it will be like this :

1. From Cpanel got to Subdomains
2. Create new subdomain with project folder name. ex : `test.farazphptest.comxa.com`
3. Overwrite the created subdomain folder with your project folder. ex : `test`
4. Edit your .htaccess in your main uploaded project folder to be like this :

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)    
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
> ```

5. now you can call your project directly from the new subdomain url.

ex : `http://test.farazphptest.comxa.com`